# What happens in FreePascal if field F of Class C is assigned to pointer P after P is set to nil?

Tags: pointers, pascal, freepascal, fpc, pass-by-reference

The goal is to add a list of edges to a graph using instances of TList. TList is a standard list class in FreePascal, with an iterator interface and other creature comforts.

Here is my idea in FreePascal code:

```
PROGRAM PassPointerToClass;
TYPE
  class C
  // ...
  public
    F : TList;
  end; // end of class definition

VAR
  P : TList;
  i : integer;

BEGIN
  O := C.Create;
  i := 2;
  P := TList.Create;
  P.Add(@i);
  O.F := P;
  P := Nil;
END.
```

Is

1. F=Nil
2. F^[0]=2, or
3. something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P is a pointer to a heap allocated class.
O.F is assigned the same value as P.

Setting P to nil does not affect the allocated heap object.

O.F still points to this object and F[0]^ is 2.